# ng-bind-html not processing INPUT

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to bind html with the content of `$scope.value = "<input type=text name=a>"`

Nothing is inserted inf the DOM, but if `$scope.value = "Hello <i>Guys</i>"` everything is fine.

Is there a limitation/bug with ng-bind-html? Is there a workaround?

I am using  1.2.4 version of angularJS

Thanks for your help, this is a big issue for my development

Christophe

Comment: What is your issue?  Can you put an empty DOM element instead of empty text?

Comment: Do you mean bg-bdin-html or ng-bind-html?

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use a Directive instead of that? This way I think you get rid of your problem

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

https://egghead.io/search?q=directive

A small example:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    // you can set 'transclude: true' instead of the following line to create a new scope but inheriting from the parent
    scope: false, // this will make the directive have the same scope as the parent
    templateUrl: 'my-html-template.html'// you can load the template like this
    // You can also use 'template' and include the html code here
  }
});
```